# Is it possible to stack objects in an object diagram with PUML?

Tags: puml

Is it possible to stack multiple objects in a PUML object diagram? Or give them a kind of "shadow"?

I want to achieve a visual effect like so:

```
    +------------+
    |            |
  +------------+ |
  |            | |
+------------+ | |
|            | | |
| Some text  | |-+
|    here    | |
|            |-+
|            |
+------------+
```

or a bit denser:

```
  +------------+
 +------------+|
+------------+||
|            |||
| Some Text  |||
|    here    ||+
|            |+
+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible, but you can use "collections" as the object type with additional shadow.

The code

```
@startuml
allowmixing
skinparam shadowing true
object firstObject

collections collection [
  This is a **long** description
  with a bullet list
  * foo
  * bar
]
@enduml
```

will create

[image]

or try it online here:

https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/HOv13eD024Ntd8BrdC8RTDDTqmNggBGu6C3OunTDan8MBvz7yZiFijXN0HBHO-KFjndypMqZenLzeL6Fp31ihm3Ql-eGEB5vt2u665GaWRKv_XaVW3dtXHrp2KiHRNCfE5OVZBTJkfI3Oybxl-TheB375HUSL7_Kay4Jkjh6i-eN

Comment: Thanks. With that I get indeed a stacked box with shadow. Unfortunately - it seems - one can not add a bullet list to it, i.e. something like `collections "bbX" as BBx {\n
 * name\n
 * version\n
}`

Comment: I have edit the answer to show you how to add a bullet list.

Comment: Superb! Thanks! I obviously had tried using the wrong brackets.